# storing image file in php

Tags: php, image, file, upload, store

I'm trying to save my file in a root directory. but I keep getting below error.

**Warning: move_uploaded_file(../upload/dddd1.png) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test-website/process/uploadchecker.php on line 48**

I want to save the image to  :
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test-website/uploads

bellow is my php code.

```
 $allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");
                $extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["upload_file"]["name"]));

                if ((($_FILES["upload_file"]["type"] == "image/gif")|| ($_FILES["upload_file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")||($_FILES["upload_file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")|| ($_FILES["upload_file"]["type"] == "image/png"))&& ($_FILES["upload_file"]["size"] < 200000)&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts)){
                   if ($_FILES["upload_file"]["error"] > 0){
                        echo "Error: " . $_FILES["upload_file"]["error"] . "<br />";
                    }else{
                    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["upload_file"]["name"] . "<br />";
                    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["upload_file"]["type"] . "<br />";
                    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["upload_file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
                    echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["upload_file"]["tmp_name"];


                        if (file_exists("../uploads/" . $_FILES["upload_file"]["name"]))
                          {
                          echo $_FILES["upload_file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
                          }
                        else
                          {
                          move_uploaded_file($_FILES["upload_file"]["tmp_name"],"../upload/" . $_FILES["upload_file"]["name"]);
                          echo "Stored in: " . "../uploads/" . $_FILES["upload_file"]["name"];
                          }

                   }
                  }else{
                    echo "Invalid file";
                  }
```

Comment: What permissions do you have on the test-website/uploads/ folder?

Comment: And does the folder uploads really exist?

Comment: I've tried all permissions.. but now is on 755

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your file moving path is woring you have to use upload directory

```
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES["upload_file"]["tmp_name"],"../upload/" . $_FILES["upload_file"]["name"]);
```

use

**uploads**

inseted of

**upload**

**try this**

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["upload_file"]["tmp_name"],"../uploads/" . $_FILES["upload_file"]["name"]);
```

Comment: god bless you man ... I look into this code over 100 times ... thanks